# Visualising time difference between two fields in Elasticsearch and Kibana

Tags: date, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I'm trying to visualize the time difference (in hours) between two date fields.

The fields are declared like this:

```
 "fieldname": {
     "type": "date"
  },
```

The solution I found was:

```
,
  "script_fields" : {
    "timedifference" : {
      "script" : "doc['loading_startTime'].value - doc['startTime'].value"
    }
  }
```

The result I get is as follows:

[image]

I'd like this number to be in either seconds, minutes or hours, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
"script_fields" : {
  "timedifference" : {
    "script" : "def msDiff = (doc['loading_startTime'].value - doc['startTime'].value); return [msDiff/1000.0, msDiff/60000.0, msDiff/3600000.0]"
  }
}
```

It's going to return an array with all the differences you need, i.e.

```
"fields": {
    "timedifference": [
        2700,                <-- difference in seconds
        45,                  <-- difference in minutes
        0.75,                <-- difference in hours
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey again, I should put you on speed dial you're so damn quick! This however hides my data, I'd like to see the other data as well.

(also, how could I get the minutes difference in kibana)

Comment: You can just return `msDiff` in the array as well and you'll get milliseconds difference as well.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. This only returns the "fields" object but I'd like the _source object as well.

Any tip for getting this in Kibana?

Comment: You should compute that difference at indexing time so you have a real field to use in Kibana, besides it's much more performant than running scripts at runtime.

Comment: Yeah thats what several online sources said, I didn't want to do that at first because Es seems so powerful, anyways.... I'll accept your answer and wish you a good weekend!